# Internal Server Error 500 on AJAX request

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I am getting "internal server error 500".

I am unable to hit the Action, it give "Internal Server Error 500" when I Inspect Element.

It works fine locally, but when I deploy/publish it on client server then it does not Hit the URL.

I don't know what goes wrong.

Here it is my AJAX:

```html
    jQuery2(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery2('#fileupload').fileupload({

            dataType: 'json',
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("UploadExcelFile", "PurchaseOrder")',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            autoUpload: true,
            done: function (e, data) {
               jQuery2('#filepath').val(data.result.FileName);
            },

            error: function (e, data) {
                                        
                alert(e.error);
            }
     
        });
    });
```

And this is Controller Action

```html
   [HttpPost]
        public ContentResult UploadExcelFile(string filepath, LapTopDetail REC)
        {
            //var fileSavePath="";
            DataTable dt_Excel_Data = null;
            string savedFilePath = "";
            string FileName = "";
            int count = 0;
            try
            {
                foreach (string file in Request.Files)
                {
                    HttpPostedFileBase hpf = Request.Files[file] as HttpPostedFileBase;
                    if (hpf.ContentLength == 0)
                        continue;
                    savedFilePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Attachments/LapTopDetailFiles/"), Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName));
                    FileName = hpf.FileName;
                    hpf.SaveAs(savedFilePath); // Save the fil
                }
                BllClsPurhcaseOrder objclsPO = new BllClsPurhcaseOrder();

                FileStream stream = System.IO.File.Open(savedFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

                IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
                DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet();
                excelReader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;
                DataSet resultDs = excelReader.AsDataSet();
                SetTargetPriceDT REC_DT = new SetTargetPriceDT();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt_Excel_Data = resultDs.Tables[0];

                              if (dt_Excel_Data.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    int intCondition = 9;
                    int POID = Convert.ToInt32(REC.PO_ID);

                    count = objclsPO.SaveTempExcelFile(intCondition, POID, dt_Excel_Data);
                }
                return Content("{\"FileName\":\"" + FileName + "\",\"RowsEffected\":\"" + count + "\",\"Item_Original_SrNo\":\"" + string.Format("{0} bytes", count) + "\"}", "application/json");

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

             return Content("{\"FileName\":\"" + ex.Message + "\",\"RowsEffected\":\"" + count + "\",\"Item_Original_SrNo\":\"" + string.Format("{0} bytes", count) + "\"}", "application/json");

            }

        }
```

Comment: Just log what error you are getting using `error: function (jqXHR,errorResponse,error) {console.log(jqXHR.responseText);}` and let me know!

Comment: It returns the  HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Comment: the means the `url` its not finding... do one thing change your `url` to normal one like `url: '/PurchaseOrder/UploadExcelFile',` and change `dataType` to `text` instead of `json`

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the solution..

There were Ajax permission issue on my client server..
Write Permission was disables,so i checked Write permission and now 
its working Fine